# flowchart using digraph in Diagrammer

Tags: r, diagrammer

I'm trying out DiagrammeR to build some flowcharts and I'm interested in knowing whether I can include values from a secondary data frame (data pulled from a SQL database).

I'm using an example from the [documentation](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/90261_ad00e95221e14a33a50f2ebb56d34ab8.html) and I want to add a random value from the Iris dataset.

I wish to add `iris[2,4]` as a subtext to the `ELEPHANT` node in my code below, is this possible?

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph {

  # graph attributes
  graph [overlap = true]

  # node attributes
  node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica,
        color = blue]

  # edge attributes
  edge [color = gray]

  # node statements
  A; B; C; D; ELEPHANT
  F [color = black]

  # node attributes
  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width = 0.9]

  # node statements
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

  # edge statements
  A->1; B->2                   // gray
  B->3 [color = red]           // red
  B->4                         // gray
  C->A [color = green]         // green
  1->D; ELEPHANT->A; 2->4; 1->5; 1->F // gray
  ELEPHANT->6; 4->6; 5->7; 6->7       // gray
  3->8 [color = blue]          // blue
}
")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what I'm looking for is a parameterized diagram which is detailed here https://mikeyharper.uk/flowcharts-in-r-using-diagrammer/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding 2 simple steps, please see the example code and comments below:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph {

  # graph attributes
  graph [overlap = true]

  # node attributes
  node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica,
        color = blue]

  # edge attributes
  edge [color = gray]

  # node statements
  A; B; C; D; ELEPHANT[label = '@@1']  # Here calls label from 1 below
  F [color = black]

  # node attributes
  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width = 0.9]

  # node statements
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

  # edge statements
  A->1; B->2                   // gray
  B->3 [color = red]           // red
  B->4                         // gray
  C->A [color = green]         // green
  1->D; ELEPHANT->A; 2->4; 1->5; 1->F // gray
  ELEPHANT->6; 4->6; 5->7; 6->7       // gray
  3->8 [color = blue]          // blue
}

[1]:  paste0('iris[2, 4] is ', iris[2, 4])  # here is the label and value
")
```

You should be able to see the same result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWpxt.png)